# Some help by understanding the logic of a CTE

Tags: sql

Recently I stumbled upon a common table expression, a recursive query to display hierarchical data (see picture below with the query and (partly) result).
I understand how the query is build up and in general what it does, but I don't get the logic that is involved in getting the right levels by each row by the use of an inner join.
Can someone please clarify me for this?
So my question is how 'calculates' the query that row 3 is level 1, row 7 is level 2 and row 8 is level 3, etc.
Thanks in advance. Arjen. [image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrgReport` is the name of this named query. It is defined in this CTE, and (as a specialty of recursive CTEs), note that is is also used in the second "recursive" part of the query.

In the first "anchor" part, `0` is selected into the `Level` column (column name defined at first line).

In the second "recursive" part, the value of `Level` column is computed as `Level + 1`. Since `Employee` table contains no such column, the `Level` in the `Level + 1` expression references the `Level` column from `OrgReport` named query, thus the `Level` value of the row at next level in hierarchy is the level of the row on previous hierarchy level, increased by one.

The logic behind the `JOIN` with itself is roughly "join the result you have so far with employees whose manager is in the result you already have, then add those employees to the result (with increased `Level` value)". Repeat as long as new rows are being added.

The important bit of information perhaps is that while the "anchor" part is only performed once at the start, the "recursive" part is repeatedly being performed (and therefore possibly new rows of `Empolyees` table being selected by the join condition) - the second part is repeated as long as new rows are being added, i.e. as long as the query returns any rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the anchor part I fully understand. Only the logic behind the join is still unclear to me :(. I don't understand how an inner join could achieve all this..

Comment: First, get inital data from anchor part. Then, join this data to employees whose manager is in the initial data (as per the recursive part), and add new rows to the result. Then, take these new rows and join them with the employees as per the recursive part *again* and add the new rows to result - and keep doing this as long as new rows are being added.

Comment: Thank you Jiri, I finally understand it! Could you tell me how you came up to all this, just logic? Actually I want to become a business intelligence developer (being application manager right now) but I'm now little worried as I didn't understood this thing right away :p

Comment: From documentation and by trying it out in a test database. Not sure which dialect though, I've dealt with recursive queries (this or similar forms) in Teradata, MSSQL and Oracle, so I don't know anymore which documentation was the most helpful.

Comment: This looks like a good doc: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you Jiri, that is a very helpful document indeed!